# How to validate particular fields in a form before saving the entire form in Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a jsf form to save the data,in this form there is fileuploaded component of primefaces, for each and every file I upload, it has some particular description. I am using event listener for this operation.Now my requirement is I want to restrict the user that when I upload the file without adding the description then it has to display the validation message that "please add description" But this process should be done before I submit the whole form.

Source Code:

```
<h:panelGrid id="ff" columns="2" cellpadding="8">

                    <p:outputLabel for="file" value="Description:" styleClass="label"
                                style="font-weight:bold" />
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="30" id="file"
                                value="#{manageProject.desc}" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Please enter the File desccription" styleClass="input"
                                counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" >
                                <p:ajax listener="#{manageProject.handlefiles()}"></p:ajax>
                                </p:inputTextarea>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                        <p:fileUpload 
                            fileUploadListener="#{manageProject.handleFileUpload}"
                            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" multiple="false"  update="ff"
                            sizeLimit="5242880" fileLimit="3" invalidSizeMessage="maximum file size should be 5mb"
                             >

                            </p:fileUpload>
```

BeanClass:

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) { 

        docs=new Docs();

        try {

                byte[] data = new byte[(int) event.getFile().getSize()
                                        ];
            inputStreams = event.getFile().getInputstream();

                                        inputStreams.read(data);
                                        docs.setImage(data);
                                        docs.setName(event.getFile().getFileName());
                                        System.out.println("desc="+desc);
                                        docs.setDesc(desc);
                                        docses.add(docs);                       
                                         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(event.getFile().getFileName()+" "+"has been uploaded.");  
                                            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
        }
```

Comment: I really don't understand your problem. The button's action method already won't be invoked if there's a validation error. So it's already not possible to process the form submit when there's a validation error. What exactly do you mean with *"this process should be done before I submit the whole form."* then? When exactly is that?

Comment: In my page there are many fileds other than which I mentioned in question.Actually If I upload the file it will directly go to bean class and save the file and description of that file ,If user didnt add the description and he tries to upload the file then it should show the validation error.

Comment: I still don't understand you. You already have a `required="true"` there. Or do you mean that the validation error didn't show up? Did you thought about placing a `<h|p:message(s)>`?

Comment: description field is above the fileupload filed. If I skips the description filed and try to upload the file then validation error should come.I am not submiting the entire form.validation error should show before submiting the form.

Comment: @AmitSharma.. You already have `required=true` on description input text area. So, If you don't enter text in that field you should get a validation error which stops the form submission. Isn't that happening?

Comment: I guess that he somehow expected that all other inputs are also submitted when a file is been uploaded via `<p:fileUpload mode="advanced">`.

Comment: @balusC:i am not submitting all the fileds,i am submitting only description filed via <p:fileupload>,So i want to validate the description field only while upload a file,if user didn't enter the description and he try to upload the file then validation message should come.But validation message coming after submitting entire form.